# how to receive mobile phone sms on my web page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sms, gateway

I m making a recharge portal in ASP.net in that i need to receive the customer response and process it automatically for that i have gone through many articles and blogs but couldn't understand how to achieve it....i have implemented how to send sms from my webpage to mobile phones using nowSMS gateway but not getting the solution how to receive messages from mobile phone to my webpage..........
please give me simple solution to solve it....and also the source code for the Web Service which i need to implement to receive response from mobile phones...and gateway...

Answer (score 2):

Using Two way SMS Service, you can get this service by
http://www.solutions4mobiles.com/en/sms-services/2way-sms.html